# Why is the result from this controller action null?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq, xunit

I'm starting a new project from scratch. Currently I'm working through design of some elements and attempting to implement unit testing early on. The problem, the unit tests are failing due to what appears to be a null response from a controller action. In the Watch Window, `actionResult` displays "Internal error in the expression evaluator" and `contentResult` is null.

How do I fix this?

xunit 2.2.0.3545, Moq 4.7.63.0

Here is the unit test (xunit):

```
// Used in the unit tests
private List<City> cities = new List<City>
{
 new City { City_Name = "Chicago", City_Code = 1 },
 new City { City_Name = "New York", City_Code = 2 },
 new City { City_Name = "Seattle", City_Code = 3 }
};

[Fact]
public async Task Get_AllCities_PropertiesArePopulated()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockService = new Mock<ICityService>();
    mockService.Setup(x => x.GetCities()).ReturnsAsync(this.cities);

    var controller = new CityController(mockService.Object);

    // Act
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = await controller.GetCities();
    var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<City>>;

    foreach (var city in contentResult.Content)
    {
        // doesn't get here due to .Content being null.
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class CityController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ICityService cityService;

    public CityController(ICityService svc)
    {
        this.cityService = svc;
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCities()
    {
        var cities = await this.cityService.GetCities();

        if (!cities.Any())
        {
            return this.BadRequest();
        }

        return this.Ok(cities);
    }
}
```

The service interface:

```
public interface ICityService
{
    Task<IEnumerable<City>> GetCities();
}
```

Comment: Try calling `.Result` on `actionResult` since `GetCities` returns a `Task<T>`

Comment: @Kyle - actionResult, Status = RanToCompletion, Result = "System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[X.Y.Z.Entities.City]]". This appears correct but contentResult is still null.

Comment: @DenaliHardtail that is because you are casting to the wrong type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetCities` return `IEnumerable<City>`

```
Task<IEnumerable<City>> GetCities();
```

but in the cast of the test you cast it to the wrong type using `List<City>`

```
var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<City>>;
```

When you should be using `IEnumerable<City>`

```
var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<City>>;
```